# Typescript convert unknown type to interface type

Tags: typescript

I'd like to write a function `asA` that takes a parameter of type `unknown` and returns it as a specific interface type `A`, or throws an error if the parameter doesn't match the interface type `A`.

The solution is supposed to be robust. I.e. if add a new field to my interface type `A`, the compiler should complain about my function missing a check for the new field until I fix it.

Below is an example of such a function `asA`, but it doesn't work. The compiler says:

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '"a"'
>   can't be used to index type '{}'. Property 'a' does not exist on type
>   '{}'.(7053)

```
interface A {
    a: string
}

function asA(data:unknown): A {
    if (typeof data === 'object' && data !== null) {
        if ('a' in data && typeof data['a'] === 'string') {
            return data;
        }
    }
    throw new Error('data is not an A');

}

let data:unknown = JSON.parse('{"a": "yes"}');
let a = asA(data);
```

How can I write a function `asA` as outlined above?

I'm fine with using typecasts, e.g. `(data as any)['a']`, as long as there are no silent failures when new fields are added to `A`.

Comment: `return data as A;`

Comment: If you decide to use the custom solution let me know if you have any issues with it, it was written in about 5 mins just for this answer so it's not exactly battle tested, but i can work on it if someone actually wants to use it :)

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir The types in my app are more complicated, so I'm not sure if this approach will "scale", but I'll give it a try and let you know what problems I run into : ).

Comment: @FelixGeisendörfer I'm sure things are more complicated, I was thinking of that when I made it composable, as for interface `B`. But yeah, it depends on what your app is. You could go the other way.. define the validation object and derive the interface from it, I have a talk about something similar: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wNsKJMSqtAk&list=PL701JjUqw62nHoRho4RJ3KJSLCRG08r1Z&index=3

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use an existing solution such as [`typescript-is`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/typescript-is), although that may require you switch to `ttypescript` (a custom build of the compiler that allows plugins)

If you want a custom solution, we can build one in plain TS. First the requirements:

- Validate that a property is of a specific type
- Ensure that new fields are validated.

The last requirement can be satisfied by having an object with the same keys as `A`, with all keys required and the value being the type of the property. The type of such an object would be `Record<keyof A, Types>`. This object can then be used as the source for the validations, and we can take each key and validate it's specified type:

```
interface A {
  a: string
}

type Types = "string" | "number" | "boolean";
function asA(data: unknown): A {
  const keyValidators: Record<keyof A, Types> = {
    a: "string"
  }
  if (typeof data === 'object' && data !== null) {
    let maybeA = data as A
    for (const key of Object.keys(keyValidators) as Array<keyof A>) {
      if (typeof maybeA[key] !== keyValidators[key]) {
        throw new Error('data is not an A');
      }
    }
    return maybeA;
  }
  throw new Error('data is not an A');

}

let data: unknown = JSON.parse('{"a": "yes"}');
let a = asA(data);
```

[Play](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=24&ssc=19&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgILIN4FgBQzlwBcyAzmFKAOa4C+uuYAngA4oAqLEJyAvMgERkKISv2QAfASACuAWwBG0MZP7yA9moA2EOCH4BuXDGkgEYYGpAESqABQATOGCLITAaxBqA7iACUxdGw8ZARLMmQ3CEYANThNYEcwNSgSYgAlCFCoewAeSMY1GDQAGmQOVhIAPl5MXHx8F0FyKn465Dpg4CLbJlZC5ES4Xh4+AHI1eQArTLBR5AAyeYGnIYBCEeQZTU1fWuD8bTBkWThGRXQ+Qes0NvwYZORbUJBw-OR+gHkpmYA6fJJbPlYvFEskSLs4NxUFAoKc8lF+qhKrsgvV6l1Hr0IP0TmcIKgANr5AC6yHWfCBcQSTjBRKixJRtzRyDAAAsoN5NhAvMgAKIw5K2UZXYDcTxHXRoUa+Qz7eodNEK+pQCBgaRQKy486y-BKtkcnkgbl8gVQIUisVqCVWVDS2W0eg4Q7LZzEdyeHw1ABSAGUPgA5H7MOApCBCjD8OD8Yj8Rhcfg0O24Z1DPiQuyDGVAA)

We could go further, and make a generic factory function that can validate for any object type and we can also allow some extra things, like specifying a function, or allowing optional properties:

```
interface A {
  a: string
  opt?: string
  // b: number // error if you add b
}

function asOptional<T>(as: (s: unknown, errMsg?: string) => T) {
  return function (s: unknown, errMsg?: string): T | undefined {
    if (s === undefined) return s;
    return as(s);
  }
}

function asString(s: unknown, errMsg: string = ""): string {
  if (typeof s === "string") return s as string
  throw new Error(`${errMsg} '${s} is not a string`)
}

function asNumber(s: unknown, errMsg?: string): number {
  if (typeof s === "number") return s as number;
  throw new Error(`${errMsg} '${s} is not a string`)
}

type KeyValidators<T> = {
  [P in keyof T]-?: (s: unknown, errMsg?: string) => T[P]
}

function asFactory<T extends object>(keyValidators:KeyValidators<T>) {
  return function (data: unknown, errMsg: string = ""): T {
    console.log(data);
    if (typeof data === 'object' && data !== null) {
      let maybeT = data as T
      for (const key of Object.keys(keyValidators) as Array<keyof T>) {
        keyValidators[key](maybeT[key], errMsg + key + ":");
      }
      return maybeT;
    }
    throw new Error(errMsg + 'data is not an A');
  }
}

let data: unknown = JSON.parse('{"a": "yes"}');
const asA = asFactory<A>({
  a: asString,
  opt: asOptional(asString)
  /// b: asNumber
})
let a = asA(data);

interface B {
  a: A
}

const asB = asFactory<B>({
  a: asA
})

let data2: unknown = JSON.parse('{ "a": {"a": "yes"} }');
let b = asB(data2);
let berr = asB(data);
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=60&pc=22#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgILIN4FgBQzlwBcyAzmFKAOa74D2ADmAPzFkUjV7ID03yARsRABXALb9oPPtCi0oyYDGQBPWsIIATDQNwBfXLhjCQCMMFogCJAPKNzIOABsAPABUAfAAo4JYp9-IxgDWILQA7iAANMgyALIklCyk5FQAlMgAvO7IrunYXFAQYMJQlkYmZhbI-sTBoRHRcQlJbGnErsgAPoEgGhAwoBDa+fj4itUkmRkZPX0DIEPphcWlpADcNKPLJZY+-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-CVxBFVDZUVVVyDVdF8X8D8PjHdtcA-cja0yvIG0Y+eBxAA)

Comment: Nice! Having to provide an example value is a little annoying in terms of boilerplate, but the solution seems to be robust! Thanks for the idea.

Answer (score 6):

Aside of libraries like [ts-json-validator](https://github.com/ostrowr/ts-json-validator) you can use "[user-defined type guards](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards)" but it may become a bit verbose doing this for many types.

With type guards you can do something like this. Note that the function I wrote returns true or false, but its return type is annotated as `data is A`.

```
interface A {
  a: string
}

function assertIsA(data: unknown): data is A {
  const isA = (typeof data === 'object') && ('a' in (data as any) && typeof (data as any)['a'] === 'string')
  if (isA === false)
    throw new Error('data is not an A');
  return isA
}

let data: unknown = JSON.parse('{"a": "yes"}');

if (assertIsA(data)) { // returns true
  console.log(data.a) // within the conditional data is of type A
}

// all of these throw
console.log(assertIsA(null))
console.log(assertIsA(undefined))
console.log(assertIsA({}))
console.log(assertIsA([]))
console.log(assertIsA({b: 'no'}))
console.log(assertIsA('no'))
console.log(assertIsA(12345))
```

[try it in the playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=25&pc=30#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgILIN4ChnLgLmQGcwpQBzLAXyyxgFcQExgB7EPIo6MASSNQAKACZwwBZIwDWIVgHcQASkKjxyYETSYcyBOxLqByALzJBYAJ4AHCKxjJVcE8dMByVgCMAVhGavFyABkgWaucK7qHCJiTnCacCAWAcHIljZ2Zo6ceImKANphrgC6zm4kZCDk-jrA9oIa6C6m8AA23Io6uGAAFlDyyCAQcsgAolB9UIKuWRoDrGA5aP4A3DpQEGD0UBwN1LQtGw4xhNKyCibIAFIAygDyAHIAdFZwUNxTGABEcJ+EnxYQIifKgrWi1MxxbhQPgCaLiRQBDDIAD0yOQ602200pHoEB0ehARFYB0eLVY5DhcEecACqOQcmAPVAqW6KAJwkZbBAcBaRzUswyaRQqD2WDpPN5gtZ3BZfTkWAJRJJZIpkJ4-CEIHoLRaCIV+mJEFJ5MEauhGsEjGEEBgoAgwj1isNxtVXHVsIwVEdBuVJrNMKEeSK3sJzpVprd5o9HkIrlkri9HSdvtdUIDU3jIaVRvD-otAEYAEwAZgALABWBFAA)

If you don't need to throw the whole thing can be reduced to one line:

```
function assertIsA(data: unknown): data is A {
  return (typeof data === 'object') && ('a' in (data as any) && typeof (data as any)['a'] === 'string')
}
```

or

```
const assertIsA = (data: unknown): data is A => (typeof data === 'object') && ('a' in (data as any) && typeof (data as any)['a'] === 'string')
```

Comment: I have to say as soon as you cast to `any` is sure feels like a problem waiting to happen. You could easily mess up a condition and have the compiler carry on happily.

Answer (score 1):

@JulianG's answer is good, but as @Gezim mentioned - using 'any' defeats the whole purpose.

I've solved it with another function that uses "[user-defined type guards](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates)" to assert the key's existence. This also allows using the [dot-notaions](https://codeburst.io/javascript-quickie-dot-notation-vs-bracket-notation-333641c0f781).

```js
function doesKeysExist<T extends string | number | symbol>(input: object, keyName: T | readonly T[]): input is { [key in T]: unknown} {
  let keyNameArray = Array.isArray(keyName) ? keyName : [keyName];
  let doesAllKeysExist = true;
  keyNameArray.forEach(aKeyName => {
    if(!(aKeyName in input)) doesAllKeysExist = false;
  });
  return doesAllKeysExist;
}
```

It can be used like this:

```js
doesKeysExist(data, 'specificKey')
```

Or like this:

```js
doesKeysExist(data, ['specificKey_1','specificKey_2'])
```

And here's the entire thing together:

```js
interface IObjectWithSpecificKey {
  specificKey: string
}

function doesKeysExist<T extends string | number | symbol>(input: object, keyName: T | readonly T[]): input is { [key in T]: unknown} {
  let keyNameArray = Array.isArray(keyName) ? keyName : [keyName];
  let doesAllKeysExist = true;
  keyNameArray.forEach(aKeyName => {
    if(!(aKeyName in input)) doesAllKeysExist = false;
  });
  return doesAllKeysExist;
}

function assertIsObjectWithA(data: unknown): data is IObjectWithSpecificKey {
  const isA = Boolean((typeof data === 'object') && data != null && doesKeysExist(data, 'specificKey') && typeof data.specificKey === 'string');
  return isA;
}

let data: unknown = JSON.parse('{"a": "yes"}');

if (assertIsObjectWithA(data)) { // returns true
  console.log(data.specificKey) // within the conditional data is of type IObjectWithSpecificKey
}

console.log(assertIsObjectWithA(null))
console.log(assertIsObjectWithA(undefined))
console.log(assertIsObjectWithA({}))
console.log(assertIsObjectWithA([]))
console.log(assertIsObjectWithA({b: 'no'}))
console.log(assertIsObjectWithA('no'))
console.log(assertIsObjectWithA(12345))
console.log(assertIsObjectWithA({specificKey: 1}))
console.log(assertIsObjectWithA({specificKey: '1'}))
```

Playground link: [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIHkBGArCCwDqwYAFgMoAOewMwCA0hAJ7IDeAUMsgM5UI11GTAFw8wUUAHN2AX3bsYAVxD5gAexDIAJmojch3AKIAPYNzAAeACrIIxyCC3cxEkJOQAfZCEUBbTNCePEz%20agA2AHwAFKAUimCiajh4YAA0yADWzABycL4QojZeVgDaALoAlKKx8chmbMglWSygyFZlosoZIGoA7iAybJzIYRBgmTl5EACCUFBwLAC8yLPzTAB0ZqsLUc25%20RXIAPwTTPsook2T%20WUA3MOj4zp602FhBiZm48viihD3XD2U22GxgaighkQJCicCE52QiwiQy4XBoUQAhDC4VM6poamAKodntxXu9mEZTOYEch4GFuP9hjIKgDkFAxoooJpiaSPpSwPc5AplKoNMg4Nx6VAwKhuFhcPgiKRplEtHAwHBOiBun0QFVtGq4HVnBhkgriOQ%20AIGMxkcgEBoqVtqQAhNThCBwEBRKJgJhUNQwfXqhGLZYAciS8rAYcOADJY0HDejlj43sh49pdPpyZ9zCqDekw7xqLRrUwY%20mE77-YHVer1sX%20KWhCHw%20ZXJIYyy2WAOXiSQL5I9E5rtf1qQApMjobLrChwKD0qJh1gAIjgq9Eq6YelXMi78hoyBhEug0tlpsI5uVdbghIaAHoH6z2ZznL8IMN7SBuO71mE1EkfN60bK0hEOJ9kF6c1WlIFBvy0Yh1BAOAwkTI1kADZBqxQE0o0VC0S0EZhZHkb9f1Gf9AJPSVzzlFICOVVMwkJdhyL-ACgPFWiZXos0lSiZQtAgWgQAgLRWPYyjOJos9eMvRiolYJkKjYh0OOo7i5IvfDryicpJPU6TNNPKV5N0gTWEwUQwx6MMVLUn8NK40y6IUvTbLUGNVKkiAqJcnidIYvSAEYACYAGYABYAFZDKc4yAu0vir0s0Dm2YUQQoc3z-Nksygv4khlVYdLiJEZAwxC%20zCSAA)